# Converting Specfic column into Date Format

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm hoping you can help me with a formula that I'm using in Google Sheets. I'm encountering an error with the formula and I'm not sure how to resolve it. Here's the formula that I'm using:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("Sheetlink","Emp. Leave Setup!B4:K"), "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, to_date(Col5), Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10 WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL" ,0)
```

error is `Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "(" "( "" at line 1, column 39. Was expecting one of: <EOF> "where" ... "group" ... "pivot" ... "order" ... "skipping" ... "limit" ... "offset" ... "label" ... "format" ... "options" ... "," ... "*" ... "+" ... "-" ... "/" ... "%" ... "*" ... "/" ... "%" ... "+" ... "-" ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead try this out:

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("Sheetlink","Emp. Leave Setup!B4:K"), "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10 WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL format Col5 'mm-dd-yyy'")`

Comment: Thank you! I have already used this but still getting an error when loading data to another sheet from the result of `Answered Query` `Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: Can't perform the function month on a column that is not a Date or a DateTime column`

Comment: then most likely `Col5` is not a valid date format thats compatible for calculations. if possible please do share a sample sheet with demo data for us to check it out.

Comment: alright give me moment please